# how can I install apollo-angular on angular 14?

Tags: angular, apollo, apollo-angular

I have this error while testing apollo-angular on angular 14

Error: node_modules/apollo-angular/types.d.ts:11:54 - error TS2312: An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.

11 export interface MutationResult<TData = any> extends FetchResult {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
how to reproduce the error:

1. Create a new angular 14 project
2. add apollo-angular on the project like here in the doc https://apollo-angular.com/docs/get-started

Can you help me? I really need to solve this problem now

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UHRu.png)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [current issue](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/issues/1818).

Use the version 3.6.9 of `@apollo/client` as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you must upgrade to the version `4.1.0` of the `apollo-angular`. I was able to fix the issue after upgrading.

Check out this [release](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/releases/tag/v4.1.0).